# DBD Basic Authentication Apache 2.2

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, apache2.2

I have a DBD Basic Authentication setup. When I try to log into my webpage with this authentication it does not work. The error is `password mismatch` in the Apache error logs, and the connection to MySQL database is successful from its logs.

This is my connection string in the httpd.conf:`AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = %s"`

This table does exist, and the Column names are right as far as I can see. My DB Structure stores Username and Password in plaintext. Where am I going wrong? (I am sorry I can't provide more output I am tunneling through my Universities bespoke system to access my server and it does not allow copy pasting text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing from using plaintext passwords in my DB to using the SQL `Encrypt` function on each password stored.